# My server is being DDoS'ed with 13 gbit and my provider nulled my ip, taking down my server - what can i do

Tags: ddos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can a Software application defend against DoS or DDoS?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/241/how-can-a-software-application-defend-against-dos-or-ddos)
>   [Accessing a site (which is) under a DDoS](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6666/accessing-a-site-which-is-under-a-ddos)

Null-routed IP
85.17.154.139   8/5/12  In progress     13Gb ddos

They did not provide me any more data so far. What I can do in order to prevent further attacks? Actually right now I am clueless and still not able to reach my server. Waiting for them to give me another IP

Comment: Duplicate of [How can a Software application defend against DoS or DDoS?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/241/how-can-a-software-application-defend-against-dos-or-ddos) and [Accessing a site which is under DDoS?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6666/accessing-a-site-which-is-under-a-ddos?rq=1)

Comment: You should contact your hosting provider and gather more information. First of all you need to understand whether you are the target or a source/reflector of the flooding.

Comment: You need to trace the guys up and stop it at the source, at this level it is very close to you.

Comment: well i contacted leaseweb so many times. they said ips are fake. so there seems like nothing i can do. it happened 2 times in last 2 days. i just coded a software which will check server status and if unavailable null route ip via api. at least it will make my account safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With rare exception when it comes to a ddos there isn't much that can be done from the attacked computer / network. Once the connection attempt has made it to anything you control the attack has already done its damage. You basically need to wait on your ISP to handle the problem and provide them with whatever assistance they ask for.

EDIT: As pointed out in the duplicate question this only applies to level 4 style DDOS attacks. There are a few options to shorten response windows which can help with level 7 attacks.