# What resources does a SYN flooding attack try to exhaust?

Tags: attacks, ip, denial-of-service, tcp

In a SYN flooding denial of service attack, what resource is the attacker trying to exhaust? RAM? CPU?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_flood
You need to know how TCP works to answer this question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a DoS Attack and how does it differ from a DDoS attack?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22809/what-is-a-dos-attack-and-how-does-it-differ-from-a-ddos-attack)

See also: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4667/how-do-dos-ddos-work

Comment: Please do at least some research before posting questions. You don't even have to scroll down the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_flood) to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depends...

- it could be bandwidth saturation
- exhausting of maximum number of supported half-open connection
- service, OS or hardware limitation
- etc.