# What utilities can be used for Ping of death attack?

Tags: network, attacks, wireshark

Can somebody tell me what program can mess with pockets and enlarge them for Ping of death attack? (i need it for lab) 
Is there anywhere step-by-step instructions of this attack? I'm not a hacker (embedded systems), don't know where to look.

Comment: [The Ping of Death attack is (heh) dead](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33459/secure-website-against-the-ping-of-death-attacks/33463#33463).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, sending a 65.536-byte ping should do the trick. For what program it can do? Well a script, which you should write!

I'll hand you some tools:

- [python](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.5/)
- [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/)
- [a guide with spoilers](http://www.scmdt.mmu.ac.uk/blossom/downloads/byDoing/ScapyNetworkAttacks.pdf)

Generally if you want to look for something, you should try using google. For instance googling for "ping of death example script" which should yield several examples in different languages.